# What to do with questions related to Gimp usage?

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration

I created a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114305/create-tattoo-in-gimp) related to *Gimp* usage, because a few such questions were under the tag *Gimp*.

My question was closed.

I asked on *askubuntu* because I'm *Ubuntu* user. I know that *Gimp* is multi-platform and I could have asked on *superuser* (if they have different rules about particular applications). The other reason is that *superuser* don't accept my questions, though I don't have bad reputation there now.

Where should this question be migrated (*graphics design*, *superuser*, or another) and how to do it in my sitatuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

If it is a question about general graphic design, like yours, you have much better chances of getting a good answer in those sites, a good graphic designer, even if he has only experience in Photoshop can help you more than most people here. I'd migrate it.

But if the question is related to the use of Gimp in Ubuntu (like where does it store it's plugins, or what PPAs are there to install development versions), then I believe that it belongs here at least as much as those other sites.

Comment: OK, I migrated it on graphics design, though they closed it in a moment as a duplicate with similar question (not duplicate).

Comment: @xralf You'll want to take that up with their meta, we have no power over there.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Thanks, I already reformulated the question.